# Flutter ListView with fixed width and max available height as child of a Row inside a Column

Tags: flutter

I want to construct the following configuration of widgets:

[image]

and I can't figure the code out.

I only know of Container and SizedBox as options for specifying the size of a child, but with ListView as the child, infinity for height does not work.

I can't figure why Row doesn't constrain eg. a SizedBox wrapper with height of infinity to the actual height that is available. Does the screen not constrain it's content?

Update:
My code was this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            TopBar(),
            Row(
              children: [
                myListView(),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class myListView extends StatelessWidget {
  const myListView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 200,
      height: double.infinity,
      child: Expanded(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            someListItem(),
            someListItem(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The solution in my answer is partly based on @bakboem's answer.

Comment: Can you include your current snippet that you;ve tried so far?

Comment: Yes I can as soon as can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what turned out to work, is this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            TopBar(),
            Expanded( //The only change!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  myListView(),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ), //I think this is the closing parentesis of the expanded...
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class myListView extends StatelessWidget {
  const myListView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 200,
      height: double.infinity,
      child: Expanded(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            someListItem(),
            someListItem(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

no mediaquery, no nothing...

Comment: well it is you don't need to set the height tbh

Answer (score 1):

- You should set the width. Expanded only inherits the height.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:koreajob/styles/app_size.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(MyWidget());
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 100,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: 100,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                      ListTile(title: Text('$index'))),
            ),
            Expanded(child: Text('ok'))
          ],
        ))
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```